# Copy all columns of collection to single column of another collection on object format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one collection which have record in below format

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5fff1a4484e0d40a6e3b5712"),
"mobile" : "1234567890",
"Name1" : "Test"
```

Now i want to copy all these above fields into single field of another collection like below and few other column also need to be added in new collection

```
test_fields: {
  "mobile" : "1234567890",
  "Name1" : "Test"
}
```

By using $addFields I am able to add new fields but how to copy all the data of old collection to single object

```
db.fromcollection.aggregate(([{"$addFields":{"address":"null","username":"$name"}},{"$out":tocollection}]))
```

As you can see name column of fromcollection is getting copied to username column of tocollection but along with these  i want to copy all the data of fromcollection into test_fields column

So to collection will be like this

```
"username":"Test"
"address":"null",
test_fields: {
"mobile" : "1234567890",
"Name1" : "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation.

```
db.fromcollection.aggregate(([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "address": "null",
      "username": "$name",
      "testFields.mobile":"$mobile"//It will create an object and place username inside it
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": tocollection
  }
]))
```

You can do [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UGDTW0whr2P)

I have two docs with different set of fields and pushed them under `data` object.

```
{
    "$project": {
      "data": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
```

Comment: From collection can have any number of column and username will be on root level . Please check my sample output in question

Comment: yes, I just given an example. Your problem is bringing inside an object i.e `TestDetails`, see `mobile` example

Comment: Yes one by one I can do this. But I want to handle it from query and also in to collection from collection fields should not be at root level